# Removing all of the the headers and rows of an ASP.Net asp:Table that was populated at run time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

We would like to remove all of the the headers and rows of an ASP.Net asp:Table that was populated at run time and is now currently being displayed on a web form.

Can this be done?

Please show code-behind coding that will do this if it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [`TableRowCollection.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerowcollection.clear.aspx)?

```
table.Rows.Clear()
```

This will remove all `TableRow`s (incl. [`TableHeaderRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheaderrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TableFooterRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablefooterrow%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) from the table.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and helpful reply! That did it. :-) I will mark the question as answered later because Stackoverflow seems to have a time limit as to how soon I can do that. Thanks again!